# What are the units of IMU data?

Tags: imu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to publish IMU data in ROS vis the [IMU message type](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Imu.html), but the documentation seems incomplete. What are the units for each field? For example, is angular_velocity in radians or degrees?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239696/what-are-the-units-of-imu-data?/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2016-07-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All messages that contain fields that represent a measurement of a physical quantity (should) *always* use SI units for those fields. That is certainly true for all *core* message sets. [REP-103](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html) documents this. We can't guarantee that every author of every non-standard / non-core message pkg adhered to this requirement though. The IMU msgs do however.

In the case of `sensor_msgs/Imu`, it's also stated in the comments in the `.msg` file itself (second line of the comments in the file that you linked):

> Accelerations should be in m/s^2 (not in g's), and rotational velocity should be in rad/sec

Note also that the `orientation` field is a quaternion, not a RPYx quartet.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2